# Компиляция со статической линковкой Visual Studio C++ v142

Tags: c++, visual-c++, компиляция, компоновщик

Хочу скомпилировать программу C++ со статической линковкой, чтоб не было зависимостей от vcruntime.dll, msvcr.dll и прочего. Пытаюсь скомпилировать при помощи Visual Studio 2019 и решения. Вот скрины настроек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

C/C++ Command line: `/permissive- /Yu"pch.h" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\include" /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:none /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MT /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /Fo"Debug\" /Ot /Fp"Debug\ConsoleApplication2.pch" /diagnostics:classic`

Linker Command Line: `/OUT:"E:\test\Test\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"E:\test\Test\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"E:\test\Test\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:NONE /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\lib\Win32" /TLBID:1`

Код программы:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

std::wfstream openf(const wchar_t *p)
{
    std::wfstream fd;
    fd.open(p, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
    if (!fd.is_open())
    { 
        throw std::logic_error("open error");
    }
    return fd;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо тут смешаны дебаг и релиз варианты сборки. Для отладочного варианта следует линковать `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`. Ну и студия 2019 еще только Preview.

Comment: извиняюсь что не по теме, студия 2019 Preview она была доступна до 31 марта, а еще продлить лицензию можно?

Comment: @helldrg Но зачем? [2 апреля выкатят релиз](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs2019-launch/)

Comment: спасибо, не знал когда релиз)